# The $\delta$ notation in calculus of variations

Tags: notation, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

On page 224 of the 5th edition of *Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems* by Stephen T. Thornton and Jerry B. Marion, the authors introduced the $\delta$ notation (in section 6.7). This notation is given by Equations (6.88) which are as follows:

$$\delta J = \frac{\partial J}{\partial \alpha}d\alpha$$
$$\delta y = \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha}d\alpha$$

I know that the $\delta$ notation stands for the variation from the actual path, but I cannot relate the geometrical interpretation to the above equation. Can anyone please explain the above terms and provide an explanation on why do the right-hand sides of these relations represent the variation (varied path) from the actual path?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: unfortunately, in calculus of variations, people are sloppy with their notation, and often, if you read directly what people write, it amounts to nonsense, because often they vaguely explain what is meant. there are quite a few problems here. First of all, derivatives need to be evaluated at a certain point of their domain, so where are you evaluating evaluating these derivatives? Take a look at my answer on a physics SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/471014/calculus-of-variations-commutes-with-integrals/485232#485232 There I have tried to be precise with the notation.

Comment: that alone will probably not answer your question completely. also, while I can roughly guess what the intended meaning of $J$ and $y$ are, please include that in your question as well, so that we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommand [Calculus of Variations, from Gelfand & Fomin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CB2MK80)

Given a functional, by example:
$$
J[y]=\int_a^b F(x,y(x),y'(x))dx
$$
then $\delta J$ is nothing more than the differential $dJ$.

In the cited book you can read, page 12:

> is called the variation (or differential) of $J[y]$ and is denoted by
>   $\delta J[h]$

More details:

$$\delta J[y].h \equiv dJ[y].h$$ is the action of differential of $J$ evaluated at $y$ on the vector $h$ (here $y$ and $h$ are functions from a functional space).

In short this is only differential calculus but instead of working with finite vector spaces like $\mathbb{R}^n$ you are working with infinite vector spaces of functions.

An example of such space (always from the cited book) is $\mathcal{D}_1$ the space of all functions which are continuously differentiable in the interval $[a,b]$.

If you are not familiar with differential calculus a wonderful book is:
[Differential Calculus on Normed Spaces: A Course in Analysis, from H. Cartan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/154874932X)

Comment: yes, the book by henri cartan is excellent! also, specific to the calculus of variations, you could also refer to Henri Cartan's other book https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Forms-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486450104 It has an entire chapter devoted to Calculus of variations

Answer (score 1):

Typically $ \delta x $ refer to the change in position after $ \delta t $ have been taken into account. This makes life much easier at the Boundaries when e.g. deducing Transversality Conditions and similar.
The displacement only looking in position direction are typically refered to as $ h $ or $ dx $. The two displacements $ dx $ and $ \delta x $ therefore have different meaning and are related by the formula:

$ \delta x = dx + \dot{x} \delta t $

Let a variational problem be given by:

$ J = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \mathcal{L} (t,x(t)) dt $

If the endpoints $ t_0 $ and $t_1$ are fixed then $ \delta t $ are set to zero everywhere and $ dx = \delta x $. If the endpoints are free then $ \delta t $ have a non-zero value at the boundaries. This imply that $ dJ $ and $ \delta J $ are only equal if the end-points are fixed...

See attached figure to see the geometry

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaINM.png)

The full formula for a variation in the path are given below. Note that $ dx $ are used in the integral while $ \delta x $ and $ \delta t $ are used at the boundaries.
$ \delta J = 
\sum_{\alpha}
\int_{t_0}^{t_1} 
\left(
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_{\alpha}}
-\frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{\alpha}} \right) \right) dx_{\alpha} dt
+ \left[\sum_{\alpha} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{\alpha}} \delta x_{\alpha}\right]_{t_0}^{t_1} 
+ \left[ \left( L-\sum_{\alpha} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}_{\alpha} }\dot{x}_{\alpha} \right) \delta t \right]_{t_0}^{t_1}$